# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Performance": when installed Firebase X in Ionic 5

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

My project in Ionic 5 and using Capacitor 2.1.2. I have installed [Firebase X](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x) for capacitor using the following code.

```
npm install cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x
```

When I did `ionic cap sync`, the android installation was with no errors but I am getting the following error in IOS.

```
✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes): 
✖ update ios: 
[error] Error running update: Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Performance":
  In Podfile:
    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Performance (= 6.23.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Performance (= 6.23.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

The Capacitor IOS version is `"@capacitor/ios": "^2.1.2"`

Comment: Did you try `pod install --repo-update` (in the ios folder)?

Comment: It Worked!! There are 6 dependencies from the Podfile and 48 total pods installed. Could you please add your comments as an answer so that I can mark it correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try running this command in the ios/App folder:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: To run this command you need to move inside of the `ios/App` folder to can read the `Podfile` successfully.